# Impact on SCCs of adding an edge to a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

The following question comes from Skiena:

> Adding a single directed edge to a directed graph can reduce the number of weakly connected components, but by at most how many components? What about the number of strongly connected components?

Here is my proposed solution. Is this correct?

> Suppose a graph G' use one vertex to represent a strongly/weakly connected component (SCC/WCC) of a directed graph G. Then G' is a DAG.
>
> If the directed edge we add makes a cycle in the graph then all the vertices in that cycle are in a SCC so we reduce it to one vertex.
>
> The number of SCCs reduced is n-1, where n is the number of vertices in the cycle.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track here. To make this rigorous, you'd need to exhibit a concrete example of a graph that has n strongly connected components where the addition of a single edge reduces everything to a single strongly connected component.

One way to do that is to form a chain of n nodes linked in a path, like this:

> v<sub>1</sub> → v<sub>2</sub> → v<sub>3</sub> → ... v<sub>n</sub>

There are n strongly connected components, each of which consists of a single node.

However, if you add the edge (v<sub>n</sub>, v<sub>1</sub>) to the graph, then you'll form a cycle, and all nodes will be in a single strongly connected component, reducing the number from n to 1 in a single edge addition.

The situation for weakly connected components is different. Given a directed graph, its weakly connected components are the CCs of the undirected version of the graph. Adding an edge into an undirected graph can only reduce the number of CCs by one, since if you’re as lucky as possible the endpoints of the edge will be in different CCs that are then unified into a single CC. So adding one edge can only drop the number of weakly connected components by one.